# In Pandas, following a grouby and a pd.cut, how do I rearrange the data frame to plot by each bin over time?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with 50 data points per month. I'd like to run a groupby on the date, and then calculate the median value for each decile within each month. I've been able to accomplish this with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datecol = pd.date_range('12/31/2018','12/31/2019', freq='M')
for ii in range(0,49):
        datecol = datecol.append(pd.date_range('12/31/2018','12/31/2019', freq='M'))
datecol = datecol.sort_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(datecol), 1), index=datecol, columns=['Data'])

dfg = df.groupby([df.index, pd.qcut(df['Data'], 10)])['Data'].median()
```

Now I'd like to be able to rearrange the dataframe so each decile has its own column. My goal is to plot each decile over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
dfg.unstack(-1).plot()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, why `-1`? Some special reason?

Comment: @jezrael I know it's default, it's just a routine I got after some lengthy project to specify which level to unstack :-).

Comment: Yop, it has sense.